# Firebase Database, addDisplayName - the username & account info are not being stored on the database but account is stored on authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, userid

I have a register page which asks for username, email, password and verify password.

in firebase, authentication, it saves the account

but in the firestore - collection - users - when a new account is made, it does not populate

I'm still quite new to coding, this is my first project. In another page of the app, I do have a section where images are stored as a collection, and I can get these to render on a different page. But for the past 12 hours I've been trying everything that I could think of and I can not get this to work. please help

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./forms.css";
import "./Header.css";
import { auth, createUserDocument } from "./firebase";
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendEmailVerification,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { useAuthValue } from "./AuthContext";

function Register() {
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { setTimeActive } = useAuthValue();

  const validatePassword = () => {
    let isValid = true;
    if (password !== "" && confirmPassword !== "") {
      if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        isValid = false;
        setError("Passwords does not match");
      }
    }
    return isValid;
  };

  const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError("");
    if (validatePassword()) {
      // Create a new user with email and password using firebase
      const { user } = createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then(() => {
          sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
            .then(() => {
              console.log(user);
              createUserDocument(user, { displayName });
              setTimeActive(true);
              navigate("/verify-email");
            })
            .catch((err) => alert(err.message));
        })
        .catch((err) => setError(err.message));
    }
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
    setConfirmPassword("");
    setDisplayName("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="center">
      <div className="auth">
        <h2>Create an Account</h2>
        {error && <div className="auth__error">{error}</div>}
        <form onSubmit={register} name="registration_form">
          <input
            type="displayName"
            value={displayName}
            placeholder="Enter your user name"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setDisplayName(e.target.value)}
            className="header__inputfields"
          />

          <input
            type="email"
            value={email}
            placeholder="Enter your email"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            className="header__inputfields"
          />

          <input
            type="password"
            value={password}
            required
            placeholder="Enter your password"
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            className="header__inputfields"
          />

          <input
            type="password"
            value={confirmPassword}
            required
            placeholder="Confirm password"
            onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
            className="header__inputfields"
          />

          <button
            type="submit"
            style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
            className="header__loginbutton"
          >
            Register
          </button>
        </form>
        <span>
          Already have an account?
          <Link to="/login">login</Link>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

```js
// firebase
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

//lines from tinderclone app
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "
  authDomain: ( deleted this info ) 
  projectId: 
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

//lines from tinderclone to export default database
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = firebaseApp.firestore();

export default database;

export { auth };

// below here are user id documents addition
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

export const createUserDocument = async (user, additionalData) => {
  if (!user) return;

  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);

  const snapshot = userRef.get();

  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    const { email } = user;
    const { displayName } = additionalData;

    try {
      userRef.set({
        displayName,
        email,
        createdAt: new Date(),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error in creating user", error);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Add a few `console.log`s, add some `debugger;` points, check if code executes in a way you need and try to detect and isolate the place where the issue is happening. Also, `const snapshot = await userRef.get();`. You are missing await there. Same for `await userRef.set`. So probably there is no `.exists` on type `Promise`, your `snapshot` is a `Promise` at this moment.

Comment: I added await to both and that still didnt do the trick. I also tried to debug but no errors are popping up. I also checked out the console and its not displaying any errors

Comment: if anyone can help me with getting this to work and show me the way, send me your eth address and ill be more than happy to send a tip. thanks

Comment: Please, update question with actual code then. After changes. Also, check to code flow itself. Add console.logs from point A (button clicked) to point X (just after the await userRef.set method. See where everything is interrupted, check if userRef.set is executed at all. Also, `createUserDocument(user, { displayName });` returns a promise and needs to be awaited. or `.then()` needs to be called there. Convert your register function to async one and use `await` everywhere where promise is returned. Or it will be lost and might not be executed.